# How to make reconnecting a websocket in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket

Adding a "retry()" causes an error:

> ERROR in src/app/films.service.ts(28,20): error TS2339: Property 'retry' does not exist on type 'WebSocketSubject'.

```
 this.wsSubject.retry().subscribe(
  (msg) => this.parseAnswer(msg),
  (err) => console.log(err),
  () => console.log('complete')
);
```

[All source](https://github.com/Astrgan/ngSite03/blob/master/src/app/films.service.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
import "rxjs/add/operator/retry";
```

Comment: Does not work for me. Any ideas for Angular?